# Using arcpy AddField() does not add field or give error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes

I am adding multiple features to a geodatabase after I clip them to a polygon. I  want to then add some fields to them, but it's not working. The script runs without an error, but the fields are not added.   I've added fields to other features in the script that weren't clipped with no issues so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
original = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\layer.lyr") 
located = os.path.join(pcsi_gdb_copy,"located")
arcpy.Clip_analysis(original, AMS, located, "")
arcpy.AddField_management(located, "source", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

Comment: What is the value of `pcsi_gdb_copy`?

Comment: pcsi_gdb_copy is just a path to a geodatabase.

Comment: Ok that should work. I think you should include the parameter names in your code. It makes it easier to debug and read, and you dont need alot of empty strings: `arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=located, field_name="source", field_type="TEXT", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE", field_is_required="NON_REQUIRED")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works, but it works if I break it down like this:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"", dataframe):#get a list of layers in the dataframe

    if lyr.name == "located":

        arcpy.AddField_management(located, "source", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

        arcpy.CalculateField_management(located, "source", "\"located\"", "PYTHON_9.3", "")

    if lyr.name == "unlocated":

        arcpy.AddField_management(unlocated, "source", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

        arcpy.CalculateField_management(unlocated, "source", "\"unlocated\"", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

etc. I can write an if statement for each layer and then add any fields that I want to. I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this, but this works.